# tmux -- disable echo of last run command?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I started using tmux recently and things are good except for the fact that tmux prints out my last run command before output, e.g.:

```
~ $ pwd
pwd/Users/me
```

You can see that it put "pwd" before the directory there, which is annoying.

My shell(zsh) doesn't do this when I run commands outside of tmux.

show-environment -g doesn't reveal any weird options being passed to zsh or anything: `SHELL=/bin/zsh`

I read through the manpage and Googled around but I can't find anything.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the value of `TERM` inside tmux? What's in `PS1`? Or rather, to be on the safe side, post your `.zshrc`, because the appearance of the prompt may depend on more than that.

Comment: `TERM`: `screen-256color`, `PS1`: `%{%}%~$(git_prompt_info) %{%}$ %{%}
                                       %`

zshrc just loads a slightly modified theme from oh-my-zsh: https://gist.github.com/50dbfc87267ff500b367

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out -- needed to change my `~/.tmux.conf` to have a different TERM(xterm instead of screen-256color):

```
# act like vim
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
bind-key -r C-h select-window -t :-
bind-key -r C-l select-window -t :+

# act like GNU screen
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a

# look good
#set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g default-terminal "xterm"
set -g status "off"
```