# Zsh trouble when using echo with color/formatting characters

Tags: alias, zsh

I'm just switch to zsh and now adapting the alias in which was printing some text (in color) along with a command.

I have been trying to use the **$fg** array var, but there is a side effect, all the command is printed before being executed.
The same occur if i'm just testing a echo with a color code in the terminal:

```
echo $fg_bold[blue] "test"
]2;echo "test"  test     #the test is in the right color
```

Why the command print itself before to do what it's supposed to do ? (I precise this doesn't happen when just printing whithout any wariable command)
Have I to set a specific option to zsh, use echo with a special parameter to get ride of that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Execute the command first (keep its output *somewhere*), and then issue `echo`. The easiest way I can think of doing that would be:

```
echo $fg[red] `ls`
```

Edit: Ok, so your trouble is some trash before the actual output of `echo`. You have some funny configuration that is causing you trouble.

What to do (other than inspecting your configuration):

- start a shell with `zsh -f` (it will skip any configuration), and then re-try the `echo` command: `autoload colors; colors; echo $fg_bold[red] foo` (this should show you that the problem is in your configuration).
- Most likely your configuration defines a `precmd` function that gets executed before every command (which is failing in some way). Try `which precmd`. If that is not defined, try `echo $precmd_functions` (`precmd_functions` is an array of functions that get executed before every command). Knowing which is the code being executed would help you search for it in your configuration (which I assume you just took from someone else).

If I had to guess, I'd say you are using *oh-my-zsh* without knowing exactly what you turned on (which is an endless source of troubles like this).

Comment: wasn't maybe enough clear. Problem is that commandecho will print `]2;echo ` bedore to print what remain. Will edit my question

Comment: Problem was coming from oh-my-zsh function title that was supposed to update title of the terminal with runned command, command title hook to function omz_termsupport_preexec
To fix it I had to set in zshrc file

> DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

set -x was very useful for me to debug and find where coming from

Answer (score 4):

I don't replicate your issue, which I think indicates that it's either an option (that I've set), or it's a `zsh` version issue:

```
$ echo $fg_bold[red] test
 test
```

Because I can't replicate it, I'm sure there's an option to stop it happening for you. I do not know what that option is (I'm using heavily modified [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), and still haven't finished learning what all the `zsh` options do or are).

My suggestions:

You could try using `print`:

```
$ print $fg_bold[red] test
 test
```

The `print` builtin has many more options than `echo` (see `man zshbuiltins`).

You should also:

- Check what version `zsh` you're using.
- Check what options (`setopt`) are enabled.
- Check your `~/.zshrc` (and [other loaded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574684/where-to-place-path-variable-assertions-in-zsh/10583324#10583324)) to see what, if any, options and functions are being run.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086091/tmux-disable-echo-of-last-run-command) may suggest checking what `TERM` you're using, but reading your question it sounds like you're only seeing this behaviour (echoing of the command after entry) when you're using aliases...?

Comment: Using print change nothing of it. I tried hithout init file and was working perfectly so it must come from the configuration I made. (I used oh-my-zsh, and adapt some of previous bash config).

 I'll dig it later, not the priority right now. I'll tell what I found then.